# Auto populate outlook subject with custom date format

Tags: outlook

Is there a way to make outlook automatically fill out the subject in a new email with the format yyyymmdd? I have tried using a custom form and setting the subject value to Date() but this gives the wrong format.
I am using Microsoft Office 365 Desktop App.

For example, a new email would have the subject 20210511 filled out automatically

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop a VBA macro to get the job done. For example, you can handle the [NewInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.newinspector) event is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. So, when a new email is created you can add or modify the subject line (see the [Subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.subject) property of Outlook items).

For example, the following example creates a new email message, uses the Add method to add "Eugene Astafiev" as a `To` recipient, sets the `Subject` property, and displays the message:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myItem.Subject = "Status Subject" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```